# How does AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi know how to verify the Bearer token?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

We have an SPA that uses MSAL to grab an access token, an id token and a refresh token and caches the tokens in local storage for use later. Behind that we have a Web API running dotnet core 6 and I have configured the authentication in the startup Program.cs like so:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Then I have an appsettings.json file that contains the `AzureAD` config section.

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "example.com",
    "TenantId": "guid",
    "ClientId": "guid",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user"
  }
```

This seems to work fine. The `[Authorize]` attribute protects the controllers by requiring a token. My question is, without a client secret, how can I trust the access token coming from the SPA? Is there some magic going on here in the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` method that verifies the token?

I had a quick look in the source but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: not an expert in the topic, answering based on my own experience using [Teams id tokens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJwtUjv3G_o). This may not apply to your use case where you're getting actual access tokens client-side*

Your backend, when configured with `Microsoft.Identity.Web`, needs to reach out to Microsoft Identity platform (Azure AD) in order to be able to authenticate either the user or the app itself. That's done using [a client secret or a client certificate](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Using-certificates#client-certificates). But the tricky thing here is when does that happen and whether it happens automatically or not.

This is my experience using Teams tokens:

- If you disconnect the server from the Internet, `AuthenticationMiddleware` will make your requests fail immediately,
- If you try to call the API with a token generated from another tenant, the request won't get through due to a mismatch in the audiences.

So there's certainly some protection level when not providing that client secret/certificate, but I can't tell you with confidence up to which point.

However:

- If you don't provide the client secret and try to make use of, let's say, `ITokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync()` to authenticate on behalf of the user, you will get an exception like this:

```
MSAL.NetCore.4.44.0.0.MsalClientException:
        ErrorCode: Client_Credentials_Required_In_Confidential_Client_Application
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: One client credential type required either: ClientSecret, Certificate, ClientAssertion or AppTokenProvider must be defined when creating a Confidential Client.Only specify one.See https://aka.ms/msal-net-client-credentials.
```

- Same for authenticating on behalf of the app with `ITokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForAppAsync()`.

Once again, my use case seems to be slightly different than yours since I only get a useless-by-itself Teams id token client-side, so user authentication server-side is required and that's when the `Teams token` <--> `Actually useful tokens` exchanges happen with `Microsoft.Identity.Web`'s help.

Comment: You're right, you do need to be online for the token verification to pass, that's interesting. I assume it must need the connection to download some keys or something. In our logging system we are getting logs through that suggest _something_ is happening like that.

`User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager`